# Is there a way to get emails for new comments?

Tags: support, comments, email

Is there a way to have Ask Ubuntu send me emails when new comments are posted? I can't seem to find an option for this. A lot of times, someone asks me a question in a comment and I don't know about until I manually open every question that I participated in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New comments (answers, updates, etc) show up in the StackExchange Global Inbox in the top right corner of the screen for all Stack Exchange sites. You can opt-in for email updates by clicking the Stack Exchange icon

[image]

Select Email Settings at the bottom, and enter the appropriate information

[image]

Once you've done so, select Save you'll start receiving emails when inbox items appear depending on your interval.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that...:D Thanks!